# What relates to multi-linearity in the same way differentiability relates to linearity?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, multilinear-algebra

We know that a differential of a function existing at a point implies that said function can be approximated as a linear function near this point (local linearity).

What is the equivalent notion that allows a function to be approximated by a multilinear function locally , does such a notion even exist?

Side question that came to mind:
  Another way of looking a linearity is as a map that preserves a Vector space structure (maps a vector space into a vector space).

Analogously what abstract structure or space, tied with a structure preserving map, is related to multi-linearity.

Sorry if my Jargon is not accurate, but i hope the gist of my question is clear.

Comment: Multi-linear functions include (some) homogeneous polynomials. e.g. $xy$. So there is already a lot of complexity.

Comment: That's an interesting question.  You could imagine having a function $f:\mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ which is not multilinear at all, but which has the property that $f(x^1,x^2,x^3) \approx f(x^1_0,x^2_0,x^3_0) + Df(x^1_0,x^2_0,x^3_0)(x^1 - x^1_0,x^2 - x^2_0,x^3 - x^3_0)$ when $(x^1,x^2,x^3)$ is close to $(x^1_0,x^2_0,x^3_0)$.  Here $Df(x^1_0,x^2_0,x^3_0)$ is a multilinear function. Has this idea been studied and does it turn out to be interesting?

Comment: littleO: Yes!, I believe your formulation is spot on.

Comment: I feel that you may end up with some form of multivariate Taylor series approximation. If you allow yourself to consider $x^2$ and similar multi-linear (I think you should, since it can be obtained from a multilinear map precomposed with a linear map, by $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \otimes \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, where the last map is multiplication ), then I think you get exactly Taylor series.

Comment: well... the first term in the taylor expansion of a multivariate map is constant, the second is linear, the third is a tensor of order 3, .... the $n$-th term is an $n$-th order tensor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For later convenience, let $L^k(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)$ denote the vector space of all $k$-linear maps $(\mathbb{R}^n)^{k} \to \mathbb{R}^m$.

Let $f : U \to \mathbb{R}^m$ be a function defined on an open set $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. Recall that the *derivative* of $f$ at $\mathbf{x} \in U$ is the unique linear transformation $d_\mathbf{x}f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$, if it exists, such that
$$
 \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\|f(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{h})-f(\mathbf{x})-d_\mathbf{x}f(\mathbf{h})\|}{\|\mathbf{h}\|} = 0.
$$
If $f$ is actually differentiable on all of $U$, then the assignment $\mathbf{x} \mapsto d_\mathbf{x}f$ defines a function $f : U \to L^1(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)$, so that the *second derivative* of $f$ at $\mathbf{x} \in U$, if $d_\mathbf{x}(df) : \mathbb{R}^n \to L^1(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)$ exists, is the bilinear map $d^2_{\mathbf{x}} f \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)$ defined by
$$
 \forall \mathbf{h}_1,\mathbf{h}_2 \in \mathbb{R}^n, \quad d^2_\mathbf{x}f(\mathbf{h}_1,\mathbf{h}_2) := \left(d_{\mathbf{x}}(df)(\mathbf{h}_2)\right)(\mathbf{h}_1).
$$
In general, by induction, if $f$ is $k-1$-times differentiable on all of $U$, then the *$k$th derivative* of $f$ at $\mathbf{x} \in U$, if $d_\mathbf{x}(d^{k-1}f) : \mathbb{R}^n \to L^{k-1}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)$ exists, is the $k$-linear map $d^k_{\mathbf{x}} f \in L^k(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)$ defined by
$$
 \forall \mathbf{h}_1,\dotsc,\mathbf{h}_k \in \mathbb{R}^n, \quad d^k_\mathbf{x}f(\mathbf{h}_1,\mathbf{h}_2) := \left(d_{\mathbf{x}}(d^{k-1}f)(\mathbf{h}_k)\right)(\mathbf{h}_1,\dotsc,\mathbf{h}_{k-1}),
$$
and the appropriate version of Taylor's theorem now says that
$$
 f(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{h}) = f(\mathbf{x}) + d_{\mathbf{x}}f(\mathbf{h}) + \frac{1}{2}d^2_\mathbf{x}(\mathbf{h},\mathbf{h}) + \cdots + \frac{1}{k!}d^k_{\mathbf{x}}f(\mathbf{h},\dotsc,\mathbf{h}) + o(\|\mathbf{h}\|^k), \quad \mathbf{h} \to 0.
$$

So now, decompose $\mathbb{R}^n$ as $\mathbb{R}^n = \mathbb{R}^{n_1} \times \cdots \times \mathbb{R}^{n_k}$ for some positive integers $n_1,\dotsc,n_k$ with $n_1 + \cdots n_k = n$. Suppose that $f : \mathbb{R}^{n_1} \times \cdots \times \mathbb{R}^{n_k} \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is actually $k$-linear. Then, in fact,
$$
 \forall \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{h} \in \mathbb{R}^n, \quad d^k_{\mathbf{x}}f(\mathbf{h},\dotsc,\mathbf{h}) = k! f(\mathbf{h}),
$$
whilst $d^lf = 0$ for $l > k$, so that $f$ is uniquely determined by its first $k$ derivatives at *any* point in $\mathbb{R}^n$. This suggests the following working definition for approximability by a $k$-linear map at a point:

> Let $f : U \to \mathbb{R}^m$ be a $k$-times differentiable function on an open set $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n_1} \times \cdots \times \mathbb{R}^{n_k}$. Let's define the *$k$-linear derivative* of $f$ at $\mathbf{x} \in U$ to be the unique $k$-linear map $[f]_{\mathbf{x},k} : \mathbb{R}^{n_1} \times \cdots \times \mathbb{R}^{n_k} \to \mathbb{R}^m$, if it exists, such that
>   $$
>   \forall 1 \leq j \leq k, \quad d^j_{\mathbf{0}}[f]_{\mathbf{x},k} = d^j_{\mathbf{x}}f.
> $$

On the other hand, one can see, for instance, from Taylor's theorem, that two $k$-linear maps $g_1,g_2 :  \mathbb{R}^{n_1} \times \cdots \times \mathbb{R}^{n_k} \to \mathbb{R}^m$ are equal if and only if
$$
 g_1(\mathbf{h}) = g_2(\mathbf{h}) + o(\|\mathbf{h}\|^k), \quad \mathbf{h} \to 0,
$$
which suggests the following (nominal?) weakening of the first working definition:

> Let $f : U \to \mathbb{R}^m$ be a function defined on an open set $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n_1} \times \cdots \times \mathbb{R}^{n_k}$. Let's define the *$k$-linear derivative* of $f$ at $\mathbf{x} \in U$ to be the unique $k$-linear map $[f]_{\mathbf{x},k} : \mathbb{R}^{n_1} \times \cdots \times \mathbb{R}^{n_k} \to \mathbb{R}^m$, if it exists, such that
>   $$
>  \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\|f(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{h})-f(\mathbf{x})-[f]_{\mathbf{x},k}(\mathbf{h})\|}{\|\mathbf{h}\|^k} = 0.
> $$